# Gmail Semi conversation view

Tags: email, gmail

I have a problem with Gmail which I'd like to solve but I can't find out how. Here it is:
If I send the same mail to multiple people with BCC or CC and conversation view is ON, all response mails from all the recipients are in the same thread. I don't want that. So I turned conversation view off because I want to have a better overview for each client

Now if I have one client and I am writing more than one mail to the same recipient it also makes a new thread.

Is it possible that it makes a new thread when a new person responses but keep the same thread if I already have sent a message to that exact person?

Comment: Isn't anybody here that know an answer? Or is it impossible to do that?