# Changing name of Gmail conversation

Tags: gmail

I'm currently doing an internship and my Gmail inbox is now really chatoic. The boss constantly forwards me mails from clients.

Is it possible to change the name of the conversation, so that the name of the client is displayed there and not the name of my boss.

I've already asked another question which hasn't any answers yet [Gmail Semi conversation view](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119339/gmail-semi-conversation-view)

Answer (score 1):

Use labels.

Attach a label to each email, that way you can see which client the message pertains to. A strength of Gmail is the fact that you can have multiple labels attached to each message/conversation.

As each issue is resolved you can then archive each message/conversation so they are no longer displayed on the inbox view. You can then use the list of the labels on the side of the screen to only show one labels messages when you want to find the message to a specific client